# Turn Title bar filters on at all time

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, filter, custom

We have a number of custom lists, and on some of the larger ones the sidebar popping up is undesirable.  We added Filter=1 to the links to the lists which turns on the filters at the top, which is great.

The issue we have is when someone selects a filter the filters at the top go away.  Is there a way to keep them on all the time?   I wasn't sure how to access the onchange property, or if there is an easier way.

Thanks,

[image: Filters]

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this. but..

You could try to modify the XSLT of the WebPart.

[image]

In the default XSLT the filters are rendered when `$dvt_adhocmode` equals `filter`. I'm not sure how one would get hold of the default XSLT to modify, since you're using "online"...

Beware that this would only work in classic pages (i.e. on the "old" list view webpart). The better solution would be to design "better" views.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add "?Filter=1" to the links to the lists which turns on the filters at the top.

You can just use column header filter.

[image]

Reference:

https://sharepointmaven.com/3-ways-filter-sharepoint-lists-libraries/

Comment: Using the header filters works most of the time, but on the larger lists it opens a sidecar for the filters.   That shrinks the screen and covers up some of the data.  Also on the larger lists there is a hefty delay loading the filter values

Comment: It’s the default behavior.

And unfortunately, we are not able to keep them on all the time.